# Is there a Auth-Code Format Standard for .NET, .ORG and .COM?

Tags: domains, godaddy, transfer, domain-transfer

I'm attempting to transfer a .net domain from 123-reg to GoDaddy but encountering a problem. As you know whenever transferring a top level domain you need a AUTH code, often referred as the EPP code, I request the Auth code from 123-reg and then enter it into GoDaddy's dashboard but greeted with this annoying error:

[image: 123reg to godaddy domain transfer]

*Speak to GoDaddy...*

So the logical thing would be to talk to GoDaddy or 123-Reg right? seems not... Upon speaking to both parties... I'm no closer than solving the problem. GoDaddy insist its 123 Reg code which is bad, and 123 reg is insisting that its their stupid dashboard...

I've issued a different auth code at least 20 times now, and still no joy! so, need some advice.. is there a format that the code should be in? e.g is there illegal characters? and should it be X digits?

-

Comment: Yep, been through this with two different registrars, we never solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The EPP authInfo (its true name per the specification) is defined by the registrar at the time the domain name is created (and later on can be updated). It was envisioned that it was under the registrant control but in reality registrars are doing everything.

The EPP standard (RFC5731) defines the constraint of this element as being of XML type `eppcom:pwAuthInfoType` which is itself defined in RFC5730 which says in summary that it is an XML `normalizedString`.

Basically it can be a string of any length and any characters (except three: newline, carriage return and tab).

But each registrar decides how to built it and what they want or not in it, based on each registry specifications (they would probably set a maximum length). However, obviously, they need to accept authInfo codes generated by other registrars in order to be able to provide service for incoming transfers.

Now to solve your issue: if your future registrar is not capable of specifying why it believes this authInfo not to be the correct one, then it probably means you should go somewhere else as their technical level is not high enough (and/or their support team is lacking expertise) ; on the contrary if they can provide you the **registry** error message they get when trying this authInfo this would prove they are correct. But they are not.
So if you can convince your current registrar to change the authInfo and to put something simpler and compatible with rules of your new registrar of choice, you solve the situation.
If not, I would advise to choose another new registrar, someone more willing to help you.